# beginner 7-segment code using 74hc595

Tags: arduino-uno

[image]Was trying this basic circuit using 74HC595 but 7-segment doesn't light at all in Anode Common. When switched to Cathode common, it just stays at 9 instead. Trying to achieve changing value from 0-9 after clicking the button. The code I used:

```
int data = 0;
int clock = 2;
int latch = 1;
int button = 3;

byte segment[10] = {B11111100, //0
                     B11000000, //1
                     B11011010, //2
                     B11110010, //3
                     B01100110, //4
                     B10110110, //5
                     B10111110, //6
                     B11100000, //7
                     B11111110, //8
                     B11100110, //9
                    };
void setup()
{
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
  pinMode(data, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clock, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(latch, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(latch, LOW);
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[9]);
  digitalWrite(latch, HIGH);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the part number for the display? That would help. Also a schematic or a picture which clearly shows all the wiring.  But a schematic is much preferred. Also, all the code. Most of the time it is asked to reduce the code down to only the part that does not work. But they mean all of the reduced version of the code.

Comment: What do you mean "it just stays at 9 instead"? Your code just writes the digit 9 to the display (repeatedly and very fast), so isn't this what you want?

Comment: Thank you for adding a schematic.

Comment: @aims, if the answer works for you please accept it. If it does not, please add a comment. The goal is to create a list of searchable questions and accepted answers for others to use in future.

Answer (score 0):

If the display works when wired up for common cathode then likely it is a common cathode LED display.

Going on, it would appear that the only thing this code does is write out data to display the number "9" over and over again:

```
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[9]);
```

To test the display, add lines with different indices into the array which contains the 7 segment display patterns. For example:

```
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[0]);
  delay(1000);
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[1]);
  delay(1000);
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[2]);
  delay(1000);
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[3]);
  delay(1000);
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[4]);
  delay(1000);
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[5]);
  delay(1000);
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[6]);
  delay(1000);
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[7]);
  delay(1000);
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[8]);
  delay(1000);
  shiftOut(data, clock, LSBFIRST, segment[9]);
  delay(1000);
```

... should cycle through numbers 0 through 9 then repeat.

Adding a momentary push button is difficult because of mechanical switch bounce. Because the processor can sample the switch very fast, random switch bounces can make a project such as this one appear broken. Displaying what appears to be random numbers.

Read [how to de-bounce a push button here](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/digital/Debounce/) in the arduino.cc document pages.

The best approach to writing a good program is to remove all calls to delay(). Instead, after reading how to de-bounce a switch, consider creating a [state machine](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/statemachine/) where each button push will advance to the next state. Create 10 states where each state display a different number 0 through 9.